# How to prevent safari showing login form when calling a restful api with HTTP basic Authentication

Tags: safari, cross-domain, http-authentication

In my project my client side web application calls my back-end server which is a restful API sercured with HTTP baisc authentication, it runs perfect in chrome and firefox, but within the safari it always shows the HTTP basic login form, how could I prevent it to pop up in the client side.

And the client side app validates user login by calling the restful api and returns 401 automatically at the begining.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See an analysis of the problem [here](http://loudvchar.blogspot.ca/2010/11/avoiding-browser-popup-for-401.html).

We had the same problem *only* with a recent Safari version (all other versions were fine), and the cleanest fix was to modify the `"www-authenticate"` header so that it doesn't return a `Basic` or `Digest` challenge.

Thus, the API url will *never* trigger the popup (whether it's called via Ajax or directly). Up to you to decide whether it's okay for your use case.